# Flutter: Add an Activity/Progress Indicator to the Status Bar

Tags: android, ios, flutter

In one of my projects, I require to add an activity/progress indicators to the status bar of the device just as found in TelegramX as shown below:
[image: Activity Indicator in TelegramX]
I've found a package to add the required functionality: [flutter_statusbar_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbar_manager) but it has not been updates since ages and only supports iOS.
Any other method to accomplish the task?